# AWS loading WAR helloworld into tomcat7 - 404

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, tomcat7, war

I'm trying to deploy a simple Java Spring Helloworld WAR "app" on AWS.
I've created the index.html under resources/static.

I can deploy the war successfully on my local tomcat7, but when I deploy on AWS I get 404.
the Tomact management page is working, so I can deploy my project (therefore port 8080 is open on AWS).

I'm really new to AWS to not really sure what went wrong.

ec2 instance is linux, java installed is java 7, and tomcat 7.
any idea lead would be great.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.
I've set the tomcat7 Java home to java 8 (after updating to java 8)

/etc/tomcat7
$ sudo nano tomcat7.conf

updated to Java 8
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0"